# What is known about the complex solutions to $\zeta(s)=-1$?

Tags: riemann-zeta

I don't recall ever coming across a discussion of the complex solutions to the equation $$\zeta(s)=-1,$$ where $s\in\mathbb{C}$. How many such solutions exist? Is there any literature on this?

Matematica gives a real numerical solution $$s=0.3453726572911539895391917441487543036...$$

**References** [[1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0169v1.pdf)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0169v1.pdf), [[2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC432525/)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC432525/) courtesy of Sary's answer.

Comment: If we were able to give an exact answer to this question we should be able to solve $\zeta(s)=0$ and the Riemann hypothesis, too.

Comment: My thoughts too. I was just wondering if there was anything in the literature on this "other case". Are there multiple solutions or just one solution, etc. For example, in the case $\zeta(s)=0$ it is known that there are an infinite number of such $s$ on the critical line. NB I've changed the title to reflect what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are so-called "$a$-points" of the $\zeta$ function. There's [a recent preprint of S. Lester](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0169v1.pdf) containing references to other works in that subject, notably [that paper of Levinson](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC432525/).

Comment: I suppose this is related to "level curves" of a function...

Comment: Yes except here the curves are points :) It's also an interesting question to look at $|\zeta(s)|=a$ for positive a (which would give you curves in the plane). I'm not sure what's been done there.